# How to redirect a stream to other stream depending on data in first chunk?

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm processing files in a multipart form with Busboy. The process in simplified version looks like this:

file.pipe(filePeeker).pipe(gzip).pipe(encrypt).pipe(uploadToS3)

filePeeker is a through-stream (built with *trough2*). This duplex stream does the following:

- Identify filetype by looking at first bytes in first chunk
- Accumulating file size
- Calculating MD5 hash

After the first four bytes in the first chunk I know if the file is a zip file. If this is the case I want to redirect the file to a completely different stream. In the new stream the compressed files will be unZipped and then handled separately with the same concept as the original file.

How can I accomplish this?

OriginalProcess:
file.pipe(filePeeker).if(!zipFile).pipe(gZip).pipe(encrypt).pipe(uploadToS3)

UnZip-process
file.pipe(filePeeker).if(zipFile).pipe(streamUnzip).pipeEachNewFile(originalProcess).

Thanks
//Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are modules for that, but the basic idea would be to push to another readable stream and return early in your conditional. Write a Transform stream for it.

```
var Transform = require("stream").Transform;
var util = require("util");
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var rs = new Readable;
rs.pipe(unzip());

function BranchStream () {
    Transform.call(this);
}
util.inherits(BranchStream, Transform);

BranchStream.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
     if (isZip(chunk)) {
         rs.push(chunk);
         return done()
     }
     this.push(doSomethingElseTo(chunk))
     return done()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to read up more on streams before attempting this. I wonder why I cant just do like this from inside of my through stream:  if(isZip)             fileStream.unshift(chunk);fileStream.push('');
            fileStream.unpipe();

            fileStream.pipe(unzip)

Comment: Currently I suppose that's the only way. Modules rather just abstract this behaviour for you.
Also the API won't have such sugar in the future I guess.

Comment: When reading up on it, please be aware that this is a rather more advanced topic of Node. Few people even understand the sources of Streams. But this is okay, since when you adopt this kind of programming style you will never want to go back.

Comment: Can you recommend any module that would help me with this?

Comment: I'd suggest doing it with Node-core, since you'll only be fighting the technology of the respective module. It won't help that much (and I don't know any).
Definitely read up on Node's stream docs. Everything you need is in there. If you need more examples have a look at [stream-handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) and this nice [blog post](http://howtonode.org/coding-challenges-with-streams)

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some reading. One question: Why "objectMode: true" in your example? I'm dealing with binary files where there are no *rows* to deal with..

Comment: In this case you can omit this (depending on what the stream in front of it does).

Comment: Thank you so much for pushing me in this direction. I have now implemented my md5 calculator as a transform stream. It works great and it wasn't that hard to understand with the right mindset and a push from a friendly lad. Now I'll do the unzip-stream.

Comment: Great to hear. :) Love the streams stuff!

Comment: Got into a problem: When I create the new streams from within the original stream these have no connection with the original stream. I.e. I'll get an onFinish from the original stream even if the child streams are still being processed. I don't want to send a 202 to the sending part before I have finished processing everything successfully. Any idea for a solution to this? Maybe I should post a separate SO-question for this?

Comment: How is BranchStream transform stream used? It's not used in the example. Other question: will backpressure will be used in this case of pushing to many different readable streams?